# Dynamic SQL Result INTO Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to store dynamic sql result into a temporary table `#Temp`.

Dynamic SQL Query result is from a `pivot` result, so number of columns varies(Not fixed).

```
SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @Cols + ' FROM 
        (
           SELECT ResourceKey, ResourceValue 
           FROM LocaleStringResources where StateId ='
+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@StateID)) + ' AND FormId =' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@FormID))
+ ' AND CultureCode =''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@CultureCode)) + '''
         ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(ResourceValue)
            for ResourceKey IN (' + @Cols + ')
        ) p ;'

     --@Cols => Column Names which varies in number
```

Now I have to insert dynamic sql result to `#Temp` Table and use this `#Temp` Table with another existing table to perform joins or something else.

(`#Temp` table should exist there to perform operations with other existing tables)

How can I Insert dynamic SQL query result To a Temporary table?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your query as to what have you tried until now

Comment: @Hitesh.. ses updated qus..

Comment: Whats is the data type of values in @Cols? @user3879765

Comment: This would be helpful for you <br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943987/build-temporary-table-with-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-2008 @user3879765 <br> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/144f0812-b3a2-4197-91bc-f1515e7de4b9/not-able-to-create-hash-table-inside-stored-proc-through-execute-spexecutesql-strquery?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @SarathAvanavu..@Cols `datatype` is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below query.

```
SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @Cols + ' 
    into ##TempTable
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT ResourceKey, ResourceValue 
       FROM LocaleStringResources where StateId ='
       + LTRIM(RTRIM(@StateID)) + ' AND FormId =' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@FormID))
       + ' AND CultureCode =''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@CultureCode)) + '''
     ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(ResourceValue)
        for ResourceKey IN (' + @Cols + ')
    ) p ;'
```

You can then use the `##TempTable` for further operations.

However, do not forget to drop the `##TempTable` at the end of your query as it will give you error if you run the query again as it is a [Global Temporary Table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server)

Comment: This is going to fail when same query is running in another session

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to create a temporary table is to use the subquery

```
select t1.name,t1.lastname from(select * from table)t1.
```

where **`"select * from table"`** is your **`dyanmic query`**. which will return result which you can use as `temp table t1` as given in example .

Answer (score 0):

As was answered in (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/144f0812-b3a2-4197-91bc-f1515e7de4b9/not-able-to-create-hash-table-inside-stored-proc-through-execute-spexecutesql-strquery?forum=sqldatabaseengine),

you need to create a #Temp table in advance:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(columns definition);
```

It seems that the task is impossible, if you know nothing about the dynamic list of columns in advance. But, most likely you do know something.

You do know the types of dynamic columns, because they come from `PIVOT`. Most likely, you know the maximum possible number of dynamic columns. Even if you don't, SQL Server has a limit of 1024 columns per (nonwide) table and there is a limit of 8060 bytes per row (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). So, you can create a #Temp table in advance with maximum possible number of columns and use only some of them (make all your columns NULLable).

So, `CREATE TABLE` will look like this (instead of `int` use your type):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(c1 int NULL, c2 int NULL, c3 int NULL, ..., c1024 int NULL);
```

Yes, column names in #Temp will not be the same as in `@Cols`. It should be OK for your processing.

You have a list of columns in your `@Cols` variable. You somehow make this list of columns in some external code, so when `@Cols` is generated you know how many columns there are. At this moment you should be able to generate a second list of columns that matches the definition of #Temp. Something like:

```
@TempCols = N'c1, c2, c3, c4, c5';
```

The number of columns in `@TempCols` should be the same as the number of columns in `@Cols`. Then your dynamic SQL would look like this (I have added `INSERT INTO #Temp (@TempCols)` in front of your code):

```
SET @Sql = N'INSERT INTO #Temp (' + @TempCols + N') SELECT ' + @Cols + N' FROM 
        (
           SELECT ResourceKey, ResourceValue 
           FROM LocaleStringResources where StateId ='
+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@StateID)) + ' AND FormId =' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@FormID))
+ ' AND CultureCode =''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@CultureCode)) + '''
         ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(ResourceValue)
            for ResourceKey IN (' + @Cols + ')
        ) p ;'
```

Then you execute your dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC (@Sql) OR sp_executesql @Sql
```

And then do other processing using the `#Temp` table and temp column names `c1, c2, c3, ...`

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174979.aspx):

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished.

You can also `DROP` the #Temp table explicitly, like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp'
```

All this T-SQL code (`CREATE TABLE`, `EXEC`, ...your custom processing..., `DROP TABLE`) would naturally be inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Column list is dynamically generated how to do expect to `CREATE TABLE #Temp(columns definition)` in `advance`

Comment: @NoDisplayName, the same process/function/method that is used to dynamically generate a column list in `@Cols` variable can be used to generate a very similar list of columns together with their types in the syntax that is suitable for the `CREATE TABLE` statement. If it is possible to dynamically generate `@Cols = 'Column1, Column2, Column3, ...'`, then it is possible to dynamically generate `@ColsWithTypes = 'Column1 int, Column2 nvarchar(nn), Column3 nvarchar(nn), ...'`, isn't it?

Comment: @NoDisplayName, I was wrong. I thought that I can `EXEC` `CREATE TABLE #Temp`, but now I realised, that this temporary table created inside `EXEC` would not be seen outside `EXEC`.

Comment: @NoDisplayName, I've changed my answer. Now I suggest to `CREATE TABLE #Temp` with maximum possible number of columns in advance and use only some of them later.

Comment: The scope of Hash table that is created  dynamically will be inside that dynamic sql only. Its possible to create columns dynamically and insert into #temp in the same dynamic sql but can't be accessed outside. Its works same as SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM.... @Vladimir Baranov

Comment: @SarathAvanavu, you are right. That's why I edited my answer. I no longer propose to create a #Temp table using dynamic SQL. I suggest to create a #Temp table using normal "static" `CREATE TABLE` statement and to statically create maximum possible columns in such #Temp table, out of which only some will be populated with actual data using `EXEC` of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes. That would be a possible idea. But both all of our answers have drawbacks(not becz of our limitations, but of on the side of SQL Server). Let SQL Server bring some idea to handle this problem for various sessions. Hope for the best :) @Vladimir Baranov

Comment: @SarathAvanavu, I don't think that these limitations of SQL Server are really worth changing the server. The original idea of saving result of dynamic `PIVOT` into a temporary table and doing some further processing is questionable. I would try to do all processing that I need using original table(s) and perform `PIVOT` at the very end, if perform it at all. This kind of `PIVOT` is usually needed for some reports, and usually it is better to make reports on the client side, rather than through SQL. SQL is usually poorly suited for such tasks.

Comment: @Father, How did you eventually solve the problem? Was any of the suggested answers useful for you? If yes, upvote them and accept the answer that was most useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TmepTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TmepTable
     CREATE TABLE ##TmepTable (TmpCol CHAR(1))
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) =' IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..##TmepTable'') IS NOT 
NULL DROP TABLE ##TmepTable 
SELECT * INTO ##TmepTable  from [MyTableName]'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
SELECT  Alias.* FROM ##TmepTable as Alias

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TmepTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TmepTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is step by step solution for your problem.

1. Check for your temporary tables if they exist, and delete them.

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
> DROP TABLE #temp
>
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##abc') IS NOT NULL
> DROP TABLE ##abc
> ```

2. Store your main query result in first temp table (this step is for simplicity and more readability).

> ```
> SELECT * 
> INTO   #temp 
> FROM   (SELECT ResourceKey, ResourceValue 
> FROM LocaleStringResources 
> where StateId ='+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@StateID)) + ' AND FormId =' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@FormID))
> + ' AND CultureCode =' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@CultureCode)) + ') AS S
> ```

3. Write below query to create your `pivot` and store result in another temp table.

> ```
> DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(1000) 
> DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)      
> SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str+',', '') + ResourceKey FROM   #temp 
>
> SET @sql = N'select * into ##abc from (select ' + @str + ' from (SELECT ResourceKey, ResourceValue FROM #temp) as A 
> Pivot 
> (   
>   max(ResourceValue)
>   for ResourceKey in (' + @str + ')  
> )as pvt) as B'
> ```

4. Execute below query to get the pivot result in your next `temp table` **`##abc`**.

> `EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql`

5. And now you can use `##abc` as table where-ever you want like

> `select * from ##abc`

Hope this will help you.